# Difference between "euch" and "du"? And some insight into words like "Spiel"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I've enrolled at the institute of language to learn **German** (my family is mostly German, but I've grown up in Australia). I lived in Germany for about 2 years when I was a kid and picked up enough to have a conversation, but that was about 14 years ago now.

Two things I've come across that confuse me a little:

1. The use of **euch** and **du**. They both mean **you**, but how should they be used?
2. Words like **Spiel**. This word can mean multiple things based on it's positioning. For example, **spiel ein Spiel** -> **play a game**. Could someone help me out with an explanation on how this works for **Spiel** and similar words?

Also as a side question if anyone can offer suggestions: are there any good CDs that I can buy and listen to in the car? I take 2 hour trips twice per week so I could get a fair bit in.

Comment: About the side question: You might want to create a new question from this. And specify whether you're looking for music or audio books, or self-study things. Remember that this is not a forum - it's a question-answer site.

Comment: Also please note that it's best to ask a separate question for each topic. Your #1 and #2 would each make a good question!

Comment: I shall keep these in mind.

Comment: Ask two questions, else it gets confusing what the discussion is about, when the question is answered, who deserves the crown for the best answer. Or rename the title of your question to `Marty's questions`

Comment: Ich stimme für Schließen. Wir sollten Fragen, die die Regeln so offenkundig verletzen, schließen, bis sie geheilt sind. Später, mit bewerteten Antworten, verletzt man viel mehr Leute, wenn man die Frage schließt. Die beste Antwort ist vielleicht noch gar nicht gekommen - eine gute Antwort für die 2. Frage wird nicht akzeptiert. Richtig ist es, die Frage zu schließen. Der Frager überarbeitet sie, und stellt nur noch eine Frage - die andere separat, und dann wird die Frage wieder geöffnet.

Comment: "Essen essen" -> Eat food.

Comment: This question is remarkably off-topic by today’s GLU.SE standards. Both differences are comprehensively explained in any dictionary. Also, for *spielen/Spiel* compare *to work/work*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- du: *singular* you, as in "you are a wonderful person"
- euch: *plural* you, as in "you guys"

  - accusative and dative form of the "plural you" *ihr*, as in "I want to give something to you guys", not as in "you guys are great"
- spielen: *verb*, "to play"
- das Spiel: *noun*, "game"

> ein Spiel spielen, spiel ein Spiel

Nouns are capitalized, so are easy to pick out in written form. The verb *spielen* simply conjugates to *spiel* here and happens to be pronounced the same as the noun *Spiel*. Similarly confusing in English: *"game the game"*. If you know the sentence structure you can't confuse them though. Hint: *ein* is followed by a noun.

Comment: Thanks for that, does spiel ein spiel sound as bad as game the game does? As in should I be using spielen at all times?

Comment: @Marty *spiel ein Spiel* just by itself is kinda weird, as it expresses the command "play a game!" *Spiel ein Spiel mit mir* would be fine, but seems somewhat stilted to me. Outside of example sentences you probably won't hear either expression a lot. And no, you can't freely substitute one for the other, the grammar is very strict on that. :)

Comment: euch is more likely to be used in a sense like the you (plural) "I have something for you"

Comment: @ddeimeke Important distinction indeed, added a note.

Comment: Now +1 with the last edit.

Comment: @Marty: It was good enough for Goethe:

Du liebes Kind, komm, geh mit mir!
Gar schöne Spiele spiel' ich mit dir;
from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Erlk%C3%B6nig#Text

Comment: Great answer. Being from the South in the US I've always just associated "euch" with "y'all." For me, that's the easiest way to remember as they mean the same thing.

Comment: Du & Euch are also generally very informal uses.  Not such a big deal with the kiddies, but with older generations they might be considered rude when used on people that you don't really know personally.

Answer (score 4):

spielen:to play.

Das Spiel: {What is] played (i.e. a game).

"Play" and "game" seem like two different words. But when you look at it in the above fashion, you realize that spielen and Spiel are two different versions of the same word.

There are a number of other combinations where you have a word that seems to have two different meanings, until you "redefine" one of the words so that its meaning comes into line with the other.

Here (in my opinion) is another example: [Do the noun 'Reich' and the adjective 'reich' have a common origin?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/do-the-noun-reich-and-the-adjective-reich-have-a-common-origin/1453#1453)

A third example: halten: to hold, and Halt: stop. But another definition of "stop" is to "hold up."

Answer (score 1):

**Du** is *you* in singular (one person) in the nominative case

> Otto, du bist nett - (Otto, you are nice)

**Euch** is *you* in plural (more than one person) in the accusative/dative cases

> Ich vermisse euch alle - (I miss you all) *accusative*
>
> Ich gebe euch den Ball - (I give you the ball) *dative*

The full case conjugation of these words are

- du (nominative) - dich (accusative) - dir (dative) - deiner (genitive)
- ihr (nominative) - euch (accusative) - euch (dative) - euer (genitive)